# Typescript 3.0 Project Reference working example

Tags: typescript

Where could I find a complete working example of new Typescript Project Reference. Every example I found seems to have issue. An example link using outdir will be really appreciated :)

Comment: Asking where to find a tutorial or off-site resource is considered off-topic. That said--have you started with the Typescript language site? https://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: Have you looked at the compiler itself? I think they may be using it

Comment: I added a github example at https://github.com/stherrienaspnet/typescript-project-reference-example1 but cannot get it to work properly.

Comment: I seem to have fixed my issue using the same outDir for all project. I dont know if this is a good idea, can it be better? I have updated my example code

Comment: I still having an issue because I dont know how to work with vendor package...

Comment: Your example seems to be good as of commit fc9db50.  (With b5df0f6, I get problems because paths in `config/base.tsconfig.json` and `config/referenced.tsconfig.json` are interpreted relative to those files, not the original project directories.)  What exactly do you mean by a vendor package and what is the problem you have with it?

Comment: Thank you for the question and solution @user3119630. Even though it may not be perfect, you should put your solution as an answer (you may not know this, but you *can* and are even *encouraged* to make answers to your own questions on SO).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example:

https://github.com/rosskevin/learn-a

I keep branches there for other prototypes/attempts as well, so check the branch list (note branches other than `master` may not be working).